# How can i execute more than one script from many files in testsuites using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor, jasmine-node, test-suite

I wonder if you can tell me how can i execute more than one script from many files in testsuites using protractor without having the problem of jasmine time out ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to run more than one script via command line option, then its `protractor conf.js --suite name1,name2,name3` etc (no spaces between names).

Or if you meant how do you specify multiple files in a suite, use `*` in the path to specify all files in a directory.  i.e.

```
suites : {
    full: '../tests/suites/*.spec.js', // runs all files ending with .spec.js
},
```

Comment: In the first option, i put name1.js , name2.js, ... in config file or nothing ?

Comment: Yes those files have to be specified in the config file as a suite, like i did with `suite: full`

Comment: I got this error : cannot read property of undefined "name of script" ! 
when i do `protractor conf.js --suite login-spec` 
same error if i put the full path  `protractor conf.js --suite testsuite/login/login-spec.js`